# Titles in Embedded Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie to Ruby on Rails, and was wondering, I currently define the title as:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.first_name) %>
```

If I wanted to add @user.last_name to that string, how could I do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate strings with the `+` operator:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.first_name + " " + @user.last_name) %>
```